# First-Child psuedo class not accepted in menu in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

I have a footer navigation where I'm using dividers called from:

```
#footnav li:before {
content:'\00B7';
```

}

I can't target the first child so that the dots do not show before the first element.  I'm trying:

```
#footnav li:first-child {
content:'';
```

}

And I've also tried calling the class that is tied to the menu item in wordpress.  Since it's wordpress I can't go in and put an actual span tag for the first targeted li.    Is there a trick with wordpress?

This is the site (topic, footer nav):

http://thegoodgirlsnyc.com/holly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#footnav li:first-child:before {
content:'';
}
```

Along the way, set your `#footnav a` class to display as inline-block to fix the alignment properly.

Answer (score 0):

The css content: property is not intended to be used the way you're trying to (for replacing text). For that you'd need to use javascript instead. Content can only be used on pseudo-elements (e.g. :before) to insert text, not with pseudo-selectors (e.g. :first-child) to replace text.

A good example of where you might want to use the content property is if you want to insert an arrow after a link:

```
a:after {
    content:' >';
}
```

For more info you could read this: http://css-tricks.com/6555-css-content/

Comment: Also, if all you're trying to do is hide the list item, you can just use "display: none"